# Prolog grade counter and eulerpath

Tags: path, prolog, graph-theory, euler-path

this week I got this homework to do: count the grade of nodes in a undirected graph and test if there is a euler path in it. the function should work like following:

```
gradliste([[a,b],[b,c],[b,g],[c,d],[d,e],[e,f],[f,g],[g,h],[c,f]],X).
X = [[a, 1], [b, 3], [c, 3], [g, 3], [d, 2], [e, 2], [f, 3], [h, 1]]

testEulerweg([[a,b],[b,c],[c,d],[d,e],[a,e],[b,d],[b,e],[a,d]]).
true.
```

my first idea of the function`gradliste`is to 'merge' the graph and generate a list like this:
`[a,b,b,c,b,g,c,d,d,e,e,f,f,g,g,h,c,f]` then I count numbers of every node. unfortunately I stucked at the `merge`.

and for the second function `testEulerweg` I think I should firstly write a function `allconnected` working like following:

```
allconnected([[a,b],[b,c],[c,d]]).
true.

allconnected([[a,b],[b,c],[e,f]]).
False.
```

then I can check if there are none or 2 nodes with odd grade number using the `gradliste` function.

Can anyone help me on my idea? I'm also open for new ideas:)

thanks in advance

bearzk

Answer (score 0):

The `merge` function is simple. I'll rename it `flatten`:

```
flatten([[X,Y] | Edges], [X,Y|Rest]) :-
    flatten(Edges, Rest).
```

And I'll let you write the base case.

As for finding the Eulerian path, check out the algorithms at [Wikipedia](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Eulerian_path#Constructing_Eulerian_trails_and_circuits). The second one can be easily implemented in terms of `select/3`, as long as you **don't** `flatten` the list first :)

Comment: I still don't know how to test if the path is eulerian path, would you mind give me more tips?